# can not import firebase into my swift project

Tags: swift, import, firebase, sdk

[image]I am using cocoapods to integrate Firebase SDK into my swift project . The problem that I face is based on the content of my pod file .

when I install a pod file with the following content

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, "9.0"

target "myProject" do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end

target "myProjectTests" do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end

target "myProjectUITests" do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

I can not import Firebase (no such module as Firebase ) but i am able to import firebaseAuth and ... .

The second case is when I use the following pod file : 
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
     platform :ios, "9.0"

```
target "myProject" do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end

target "myProjectTests" do
use_frameworks!    
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end

target "myProjectUITests" do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

and I get this error right a way in the terminal :

```
     #  from /Users/veronica/Desktop/myProject/Podfile:5
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #  target "myProject" do
     >  use_frameworks!
     #  pod 'Firebase'
     #  -------------------------------------------
```

by the way I've gone through similar questions to mine and found some answers like :

```
platform :ios, "9.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
 pod 'Firebase'
end
```

but I still get an error just like my own second version 
Any help is strongly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: can you import other libraries of Firebase ? example:  

import FirebaseAnalytics

Comment: @SoheilB.Marvasti   yes I have them all ,  even if u check the photo I've uploaded the folder Firebase is there meaning that logically there should be no problem but .....

Comment: Firebase module is just a header file which imports other Firebase libraries. So there should be no problem to directly import other modules of firebase instead. Like :


import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

And so on ...

Comment: @SoheilB.Marvasti my understanding is that I have to import them all one by one in my delegate and then use them 
Am I right ?

Comment: correct, you may need to import them in this way

Answer (score 1):

In my podfile I had

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Admob'
```

I used to be able to access the Firebase libraries simply with just

```
import Firebase
```

For some reason it stopped working when I was messing around with my podfile and it would say **No such module 'Firebase'**. However it would work if I imported individual libraries

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import FirebaseAnalytics
```

That was fine but I prefer to have it back the way it was before, and simpler with only one import. I tried a few things and eventually these steps worked

1. Clean project (not sure if this was necessary)
2. Remove all Firebase dependencies from the podfile
3. run `pod install`
4. Add Firebase back into the podfile
5. run `pod install` again

Then it worked! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can't believe this was all it took.

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'myProject' do
platform :ios, "9.0"

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

Comment: Did you remove everything else from the podfile? If so, what's the exact error message you get?

Comment: I have erased every thing in my pod file and copied and  pasted your code in my file then removed the myProject.xcworkspace and reinstall the the pod file . but when I write down "import Firebase" in my appdelegate.swift it says the module doesn't exist . but I dont understand why  actually ?  because i have the firebase folder in my pods (in the picture)

Comment: What do you mean you removed the workspace? You should be using the workspace now that you're using pods.

Comment: After pasting what I gave you into your podfile, you have to do in terminal: "pod install"

Comment: @DanialKosarifa When you first create a project, then configure and install your pod via pod install and then add a line of code: import Firebase, it will flag it as an error. Go ahead and Build your project at that point (command-B). That may get rid of the error. That happens to us all the time.

Comment: @Jay I've tried both clearing and rebuilding the project actually . But the error doesn't disappear :|